# How do I know which dll filenames the games allow?

Tags: dll, patch

I want to develop patches as DLLs for games. In the patches I used before, we were copying one or more dll files to the directory where the game was installed, these dll files were not previously in the directory where the game was installed, but despite this the game recognized and used those dll files. So how do I know which dll filenames a game allows?